# pre launch report getting error in pixel 2

Tags: android, prelaunch

I recently uploaded my app to the Play but got this pre-launch report indicating that of the nine devices tested, my app runs well on eight devices.

This is the report I get. How do I solve this? please suggest me.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-2
Process: com.google.android.apps.mtaas.crawler:robov2crawldriver, PID: 15626
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No new screen state, but execution result is SUCCESS
    at com.google.android.apps.mtaas.crawler.obfuscated.y.e.b(HttpEncoding.java:45)
    at com.google.android.apps.mtaas.crawler.controller.CoreController.performAction(CoreController.java:195)
    at com.google.android.apps.mtaas.crawler.controller.CoreController.crawl(CoreController.java:101)
    at com.google.android.apps.mtaas.crawler.controller.CoreControllerRunner.run(CoreControllerRunner.java:7)
```

Any help would be highly appriciated.